# Pointer casting between types and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, casting, undefined-behavior

In C++, if `A` and `B` are different classes, it is generally undefined behavior to cast an `A*` to a `B*` and then dereference, i.e. given

```
A *a = ...;
```

It is undefined behavior to write

```
((B*)a)->x
```

Even if it so happens that `x` has the same type and offset in both classes.

On the other hand, `char*` has a special exemption from the casting rules. Does that mean it's well-defined if you write it like this?

```
((B*)(char*)a)->x
```

Comment: It's still undefined behavior.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Casting via `char` doesn't magically make it legal.

Comment: The offset for a class or structure member is usually guaranteed for a first member of the class or structure: it will have the same address as the structure, but even this general rule may be violated if the class or structure includes virtual functions, which may be located before the first member.

Comment: Okay. Is there anyway to make it well-defined (even if implementation dependent)? For example, would going via `uintptr_t` suffice?

Comment: @rwallace The main restriction is on the aliasing, not the casting. Cast it any way you like, it won't change that you're violating the aliasing rules.

Comment: @rcgldr True. Let's say I'm talking about situations where x is indeed the first member and there are no virtual functions.

Comment: @rwallace - Since this is C++, why not define a base class with the common members, and then use derived classes to deal with the non-common members?

Comment: No matter what you do you are _still_ accessing an object of type `A` as it it were type `B`. No and no amount of casting is going to magically make them related types and make the operation well-defined.

Comment: @rcgldr Because you can't use static initialisers with derived classes.

Comment: @rwallace - To be safe, you could do a run time check for the offsets of common members of classes or structures using the offsetof() macro. If the offsets and types are equal, then I don't see how there could be an issue.

Comment: @rwallace "Let's say I'm talking about situations where x is indeed the first member and there are no virtual functions." -- If to be more specific your class is a standard layout class, then let's say your `x` has type `int`. Just keep track of an `int *` to your `x` member. You can safely cast that to `A *` or `B *`, if you're sure of the actual type of the object.

Comment: @hvd Why would that be safe? Wouldn't the `B*` cast and deref be still undefined behavior by reason of violating the aliasing rules? To be sure, it would generate correct machine code if compiled in the obvious way, but the tricky thing about undefined behavior isn't an obvious translation doing something wrong, it's monkey's-paw optimisations taking UB as license to miscompile the program.

Comment: @rwallace It would be safe as long as you're not actually accessing any object of the wrong type. To inspect `x`, just dereference the pointer. No need to cast to `A *` when it's really possibly a `B *`, or vice versa, so no aliasing violation. If after that you know that you really have an `A`, you cast to `A *`. If you find that you really have a `B`, you cast to `B *`.

Comment: @rwallace At least, your description comes across as if `x` is an indicator that tells you what type of object you are dealing with. If that is not the case, then my comment may not work for you.

Comment: @hvd Oh! Yes, `x` is indeed that, and you're right, although the issue manifests in terms of what the compiler will do at compile time, it's still within the rules as long as you adhere to the dynamic types of the objects at runtime. Good point. Thanks!

Comment: Do current compilers have an "assume no aliasing" option anymore? (old versions of Microsoft compilers do). If the option is not there, then does the compiler have to assume that aliasing may be present?

Comment: @rcgldr Current compilers with optimisation turned on tend to default to assuming you aren't violating the aliasing rules. Some of them have an option to be more conservative, but assuming that option will be available and enabled and do exactly what is desired, is an assumption one would prefer not to make if there are reasonable alternatives.

Comment: @rwallace - From what I've read, aliasing rules deal with incompatible types at the same location in memory (like char versus short versus int at the same address). In the question above, the types (at least the member types) are the same.

Answer (score 3):

This question depends on the types of `A` and `B`.

If `B` is a base class of `A`, or `A` is a base class of `B`, then `((B *)a)` is a static cast, so `((B *)a)->x` is correct if `B` is the base class; or if `B` is the derived class and `a` actually points to the `A` part of an object of type `B`.

If `A` and `B` are unrelated types, then we have to look at the strict aliasing rule. Here is some concrete code:

```
struct A { int p,q,r; } a;
struct B { int z,y; } b;
static_assert( sizeof a == 3 * sizeof(int) );
static_assert( sizeof b == 2 * sizeof(int) );
```

Supposing the asserts pass, We know that `((B *)&a)->y` must designate the same memory location as `a.q`.

There are two schools of thought here:

1. `((B *)&a)->y` is an lvalue of type `int`, and `a.q` is an object of type `int`.  `int` is compatible with `int`, therefore there is no aliasing violation.
2. Evaluating `((B *)&a)->y` means `(*(B *)&a).y`, which first evaluates `*(B *)&a`, which violates the strict aliasing rule because `*(B *)&a` does not designate a memory location containing a `B`.

Personally I go with (1); I do not think that the evaluation in case 2 counts as an "access", and the strict aliasing rule talks about "access":

> If a program attempts to **access** the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:

However there is a grey area because although reading `((B *)&a)->y` accesses the stored value of the `int` object; it is not clear whether it is also considered as accessing part of the stored value of the struct containing that object.

---

`((B*)(char*)a)->x` makes no difference to the latter case, we still end up with an lvalue of type `int`.  In the inheritance case, if it is multiple inheritance then this might break the code because it turns a `static_cast` into a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Would it affect things if the code was written `*((int*)&((B *)&a)->y)`?  The act of taking the address of `(B *)&a)->y` shouldn't constitute an "access", and once the address is taken, using it as an `int*` should comply with the aliasing rules since that's what it is.

Comment: It wouldn't affect things - `(B *)&a)->y` already has type `int`. The aliasing rules involve the type of the lvalue doing the access and the effective types of the object being accessed, not how many casts you use

Comment: Given `int *temp = (B*)&a->y;` followed sometime later by `*temp = whatever;`, I don't see how the first statement could be considered any kind of illegitimate "access", and I am unaware of any mechanism by which it would "taint" the resulting pointer in such a way as to make the subsequent access illegitimate.  Is there any such mechanism?

Comment: @supercat well, I agree with you but I was trying to note in my post that (resulting from previous discussions on the topic) some people disagree

Comment: Is there any reason why `*(&(foo->bar))` should be required to be synonymous with `foo->bar`?  I would think it reasonable for a standard (or a clarification document) to say that the latter would require that the target as written as a type alias-compatible with `foo`, while the former would not impose such a strict requirement.

Comment: I think things would get confusing very fast if `*&` had any effect

Comment: The ampersand operator has always needed to prevent the rvalue conversion of its operand, meaning that `&*` would cancel, but that doesn't mean that `*&` cancels.  Prior to C99, some compilers would, when register optimization was enabled, flush register-cached variables to memory whenever their address was taken.  While it would have been helpful if there were a qualifier that was a little weaker than `volatile` to let a compiler know that a function which received a variable's address might have stashed a copy of it in a global variable that could be used by other functions...

Comment: ...the semantics of such compilers allowed optimizations not available under the Strict Aliasing Rule, while avoiding some of the awkwardness that results from it.  While some newer compilers might generally regard *& as a nop, I believe that `register int i; (*&i)++;` would be ill-formed because the Standard explicitly forbids taking the address of a register-qualified variable.

Comment: True, `&` affects register variables , and the case of reading an uninitialized variable

Comment: Given that, would it be fair to say that while it may be "surprising" for `*&(lvalue)` to have one meaning while `(lvalue)` by itself would have a different meaning, there shouldn't be anything terribly surprising about `*&(lvalue)` having a defined meaning in some cases where `(lvalue)` alone would not?  I would consider `*&(foo->bar)` a likely candidate for such treatment, especially given that the whole purpose of the Strict Aliasing Rule is to facilitate register optimization, and `*&` tends to curtail register optimization.